# tricky Android Google Map zoom while maintaining center point

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

It's not easy explaining my problem but I will try.

I have an android GoogleMap, on top of it, I have an ImageView positioned at its center at all times. If I drag/pan the map, the pin will always be in the center of the GoogleMap.

Now, I add a marker, somewhere on the map. I want to zoom such that the center point remains in the center of the map, and the marker is visible within the map, and to the highest zoom level.

The problem is if I simply check if the marker is within boundaries of the map or not, and then keep zooming in/out till it is, this process will always repeat itself, i.e. trying to zoom in and if the marker became outside, then zoom out.

The problem is I rely on an OnCameraChange listener which will keep calling itself everytime I zoom in or out, hence, the process of zooming in/out will keep occuring indefinitely

```
journeyGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition position)
   {
```

Basically, what I need is a function where I can provide the center LatLng and the markerLatLng and it will automatically calculate the LatLngBounds making sure my center is within the center of the LatLng bounds, and then I can simply use

```
public static CameraUpdate newLatLngBounds (LatLngBounds bounds, int width, int height, int padding)
```

as shown in the link below
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,int, int,int)

If you need anymore clarification please do tell me

Comment: Not sure if too late, please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30118649/764897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate `LatLngBounds` from two points:

1. Your marker position and
2. Place on the opposite side of your current center.

The second is calculated like this:

```
LatLng other = new LatLng(2 * center.latitude - position.latitude, 2 * center.longitude - position.longitude);
```

See [LatLngBoundsUtils.fromCenterAndPositions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/master/android-maps-extensions/src/pl/mg6/android/maps/extensions/utils/LatLngBoundsUtils.java#L28) for a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()` to get all four corners of screen as `LatLng` values forming trapezium.  Calculate where trapezium intersects with line drawn through center and your marker. Scale factor is (distance from center to marker / distance from center to intersection point). Now just scale trapezium with this scale factor relative to center. This is new visible regison.

You may also use `getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds` to simplify calculation, but note that some areas of returned rectangle are actually not visible.