# Disable BottomSheet outside touch in the jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

I used BottomSheet view in the jetpack compose but I want to lock the screen with bottomSheet until we click on the bottomShets's button and disable outside touching in the bottomSheet. How can I do it?

**My bottomSheet:**

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun BottomSheet(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    composable: @Composable () -> Unit,
    scope: CoroutineScope
) {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Expanded)
    )
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .padding(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Button(colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE,
                    contentColor = AppColor.neutralColor.DOCTOR
                ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        small
                    ),
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                        }
                    }) {  
                }
            }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = medium, topStart = medium)
    ) {
        composable()
    }

}
```

The composable function is a google map screen

Comment: can you provide the code for bottom sheet??

Comment: Sure, I added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sheetGesturesEnabled: Boolean = true/false` attribute, if you want to change the bottom sheet cancelable or not cancelable from outside.

```
 BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetGesturesEnabled = false,
        sheetContent = {
           ...
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = medium, topStart = medium)
    ) {
        composable()
    }
```

for proper documentation use this link: [BottomSheetScaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#BottomSheetScaffold(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.BottomSheetScaffoldState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.FabPosition,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1))

Comment: this screen (composable() ) is a google map. I want the user not to be able to move Google Map when BottomSheet is open. How can i do it?

Comment: can you give me the class which class you are using for google maps view?? and if you are using AndroidView then use : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61146384/10954249 answer on update={}, using bottomsheetexpanded or collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `sheetGesturesEnabled = false` property of `BottomSheetScaffold` to disable gestures. And if you set it with a var sheetGesturesEnabled by `remember {mutableStateOf(true)}` you can toggle it as you wish.

```
var sheetGesturesEnabled by remember {mutableStateOf(true)}
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = sheetGesturesEnabled,
    sheetContent = {
    },
    drawerContent= {
    }
)
```